# Tips on using proguard for testing

Tags: android, testing, proguard

I **need** to use proguard when running my android app in debug mode. My app seems to be hitting the dreaded 64K method limit and so proguard is the only way my apk is built successfully.

That being said, using proguard for running tests take INFINITELY long. Running it through the emulator is slow enough, but adding the proguard processing makes it even more slower.

Q. Are there any tips on reducing the time proguard takes for processing?

Some possible ideas? :

1. Instruct Proguard to only shrink and do absolutely nothing else (possibly saving in build time)
2. Ability to run tests without building the apk?

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a bunch of things, I've found that decreasing the number of things you do in your proguard configuration (like optimization passes/no obfuscation) shave off a couple of seconds, but it's all marginal compared to the amount of time introduced by proguard overall.

The wait time was unbearable, so i reverted to using jarjar and stripping off methods from my external libraries ([google play services/guava](https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/K8AHqFVprFz)). I use proguard only for release builds now, so atleast my debug builds are faster.